# Supremum of the random process

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, stochastic-processes, random-walk

Let $X_1(t),...,X_N(t)$ be $N$ independent, mean zero random processes indexed by points $t \in T$.  Let $\epsilon_1,...,\epsilon_N$ be independent symmetric Bernoulli random variables. Prove that

$$
\frac{1}{2} \mathbb{E} \sup_{t \in T} \sum_{i=1}^N \epsilon_i X_i(t) \leq \mathbb{E} \sup_{t \in T} \sum_{i=1}^N  X_i(t) \leq 2 \mathbb{E} \sup_{t \in T} \sum_{i=1}^N \epsilon_i X_i(t)
$$

This is the problem from the high dimensional probability 7.1.9(Vershynin)

I'm trying to solve this problem and already show the upper bound.

To show the lower bound,

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E} \sup_{t \in T} \sum_{i=1}^N \epsilon_i X_i(t) &= \mathbb{E} \sup_{t \in T} \sum_{i=1}^N \epsilon_i [X_i(t) + \mathbb{E} -X_i'(t))] \\
&\leq \mathbb{E} \sup_{t \in T} \sum_{i=1}^N \epsilon_i [X_i(t) - X_i'(t)] \\
&= \mathbb{E} \sup_{t \in T} \sum_{i=1}^N [ X_i(t)- X_i'(t)]
\end{align*}
To end the proof of the lower bound, I think I need to show that
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E} \sup_{t \in T} \sum_{i=1}^N [ X_i(t)- X_i'(t)] \leq \mathbb{E} \sup_{t \in T} \sum_{i=1}^N X_i(t)+ \mathbb{E} \sup_{t \in T} \sum_{i=1}^N X_i'(t). \;\;\;\;\;\;(1)
\end{align}

$X_i'(t)$ is the independent copy of the random process $X_i(t)$

Does (1) inequality hold?